How to define a Multidimentional Array in MIDL
I'm getting the following MIDL compiler error:
1>midl : error MIDL9008: internal compiler problem - See documentation for suggestions on how to find a workaround.
1>midl: Assertion failed: !"All types should resolve their own instance names", file com\rpc\midl\midlrt\inc\nodeskl.hxx, line 378
Here's the code that generates the error:
    #define MaxWavelengths 24
    #define MaxSurf 99
    typedef double RI_TYPE[MaxWavelengths][MaxSurf];

    runtimeclass ShortLensData
    {
        String title;
        RI_TYPE ri;  // Double ri[MaxWavelengths][MaxSurf];
    }

If I comment out the "RI_TYPE ri;" line, the code compiles without error.  I'm trying to follow the Microsoft instructions found on this page: learn.microsoft but I can't get the code to compile.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there really an error in nodeskl.hxx?
BTW, the code example on the learn.microdoft page in the section on Multidimensional Arrays gives me the following error:
MIDL4065: [msg]Unknown token. [context]get_rect
"get_rect" is neither defined nor used anywhere I can find.
